# Unable to display results into a php table

Tags: soap, php

I tried the force.com php toolkit to pull results from salesforce into php. Following is my code...

```
$query = "SELECT Id, Name, Phone from Contact";
$response = $mySforceConnection->query($query);
echo'<table>';
echo'<tr>';
echo "Results of query '$query'<br/><br/>\n";
foreach ($response->records as $record) {
 echo'<td>';  echo $record->Id . ":" . $record->Name . "<br/></tr>\n";  echo'</td>'; 
}
echo'</tr>';
echo'</table>';
echo '</body></html>';
?>
```

I'm unable to draw a table around my results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code:

```
$query = "SELECT Id, Name, Phone from Contact";
$response = $mySforceConnection->query($query);

echo '<table>';
echo '<tr><td colspan="2">';
echo "Results of query '$query'</td></tr>";

foreach ($response->records as $record) {
    echo'<tr><td>';
    echo $record->Id;
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $record->Name;
    echo '</td></tr>';
}
echo'</table>';
echo '</body></html>';
```

Comment: I missed a simple parameter border="3" inside table. It worked on yours as well as my code. Thanks for helping!